# Keeping audio clips in memory

Tags: java, swing, audio, memory, javasound

I am making a game and I have noticed that keeping all the audio files in memory is generally not really memory efficient as longer (and therefor larger) audio files take up quite a lot of memory. I was wondering at which size the game should decide to stream the audio file, rather than storing it in memory?

Comment: I don't get what you mean.

Comment: At what point is an audio file too large that it can be kept in memory at all time and that it therefor has to be streamed when it is required

Comment: It is not uncommon to have one long file played from file (sometimes even while being decompressed at the same time). I see that a lot with indie java games that have a background music (from file) and sound effects. A lot depends on how much RAM you have available and what other aspects of your program need in terms of RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a good practice, you should keep all audio(and texture) files in RAM. Reading audio files from ram is much faster than reading audio files from hard disk. It will make your game lagging if your game is designed to load an audio file and play it, when the audio is required, then destroy it when your game finish playing the audio.

The best way is do not load audio file when it isn't required.
For example, your game has 5 stages. In stage one, music_1.mp3 isn't required so you should not load it. Remove the audio files(audio for stage one only, which will not be used in other stage) from ram when stage one is finished.

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to be concerned with this.  Instead, try soft-referencing your resources.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html

Answer (score 1):

> ..at which size the game should decide to stream the audio file, rather than storing it in memory?

I'd do it at [`OutOfMemoryError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html).  Anything before that is premature optimization.